# How to get value of maps of build in method that have callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, redis, callback

I Have some function that need got value and return it, but in those function, there is some maps of array and inside it, i need call build in function that have callback inside it.

Here is the code:

```
const db = require('db')
function test(){
   let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
   let result = []
  arr.map(function (val, idx){
      db.get(key, function (err, value) {
         //how can i get all value and passing it to result variable and passing the result to become return value in test() function ?
         // db.get() is only return true, not return any other value
     }
  })
}
```

how can i get the data and return in redisGetAll function..

What i already do is:

```
const db = require('db')
function test(){
   let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
   let result = []
   arr.map(function (val, idx){
      db.get(key, function (err, value) {
         result.push({key, value})
     }
  })
  return result //this should be still empty array, cause result.push happen in async process, 
}
```

i know i cannot assign to *data* variable cause this is callback asynchronous, it will be still empty array as initiate at the first time..

Answer (score 0):

You should follow an async-await approach as follows

```
const db = require('db')
async function test() {
  const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  return await Promise.all(arr.map(async (val, idx) => getObj(key)));
}

function getObj(key) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    db.get(key, function(err, value) {
      resolve({
        key,
        value
      });
    });
  });
}
```

I'm assuming you know where the `key` variable is coming from.  On the other hand, remember the function `test`must be called this wait `await test()`